# Prove dependency for $X$ and $Y$ given the structure $X \longrightarrow Z \longrightarrow Y$

Tags: probability, summation, independence, bayes-theorem, bayesian-network

Conditional independence exists for two events $A$, $B$ given an event $C$ when: $P(A,B|C) = P(A|C)\cdot P(B|C)$

Bayes Theorem for two Events $E, F$: $P(E│F)=  \frac{P(F|E) \cdot P(E)}{P(F)}$

I deduced that from a relationship between the events $X,Y,Z$ when
$$P(X,Y,Z) = P(X)\cdot P(Y|Z)\cdot P(Z|X)$$ (a Bayesian network would look like $X \longrightarrow Z \longrightarrow Y$) there is a conditional independence for X and Y given Z :
$$P(X,Y|Z)= \frac{P(X,Y,Z)}{P(Z)} = \frac{P(X)\cdot P(Z|X)}{P(Z)}\cdot P(Y|Z) = P(X|Z)\cdot P(Y|Z)$$

Meaning that if we can observe the event $Z$ and it holds, that both $X$ and $Y$ are only dependent on $Z$ and therefore conditionally independent from each other.
But when I examined the case for when Z is **not** given($Z$ could occur $P(Z)$or not $P(\overline{Z})$), I don't know how to proceed to show dependency between X and Y:

$$P(X,Y) = P(X,Y,Z)+P(X,Y,\overline{Z})
= \\ P(X)\cdot P(Y|Z)\cdot P(Z|X) + P(X)\cdot P(Y|\overline{Z})\cdot P(\overline{Z}|X) = \space ?$$

### After reading Did's comment, I made some changes to the Question

I changed the use of the notations from variables to events, since I seem to have abused them and created confusion. I believe it makes things simpler too. So, for an event $A$, $P(A)$ is the probability that $A$ occurs. $P(A, B) = P(A 
 \cap B)$ is the prob. that A and B occur etc. .

I watched a video to explain different dependency relationships and it said for the structure shown above, from $P(X,Y) = P(X) \cdot P(Y|X)$ we can deduce that Y is dependent on X, if Z is not given ([Video](https://youtu.be/t2yupeDM4f8?t=1m10s), in german), which is wrong.

My question in the first place was, how can I prove that Y and X are somehow dependent if we are not able to observe Z.

Comment: Are $X,Y,Z$ random variables? If so then what exactly is meant by expressions like $P(X,Y,Z)$, $P(X)$, $P(Y\mid Z)$ et cetera? If not then are $X,Y,Z$ values that can be taken by discrete random variables?

Comment: @Typhon Is one of the options that I gave correct? I am familiar with probability but not with the expressions.

Comment: @drhab They are supposed to be discrete random variables. $P(Y∣Z)$ gives us the probability/probabilites of Y for the case that we can observe Z with a specific value. So we could say that $P(X,Y,Z)$ describes the possibility of the event that $X,Y,Z$ are true, for example. Do you know what I mean? I hope I was able to express myself correct here, I am not sure about the correct terminology here...

Comment: @Typhon "...the probability that $X$ **occurs**".. Well, then we are not dealing with random variables $X,Y,Z$ but with events $X,Y,Z$ right? This $X,Y,Z$ almost always denote random variables.

Comment: @Typhon But the OP speaks of "variables" in his question. Variable events then? There is also a summation of them. Summation over what then? Do you have understanding for my confusion on this? And you are telling me that everythings clear enough. Well, not for me.

Comment: @Typhon I allready learned "some" of it. Not enough, though. That's why I keep asking questions. You have not been able to answer them. I am not blaming anyone and see it as a possibility that notations are used that are unfamiliar for me.

Comment: @drhab If I may... Your questions are quite legitimate (and the reactions by user Typhon merely reveal a shaky knowledge of these matters). It is an unfortunate fact of life that similar abuses of notations are routinely used (for some of their devastating effects, see the many questions on the site by confused users). Here, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are random variables, say discrete, and the assertion $$P(X,Y,Z)=P(X)\cdot P(Y|Z)\cdot P(Z|X)$$ actually means that, for every $(x,y,z)$, $$P(X=x,Y=y,Z=z)=P(X=x)\cdot P(Y=y|Z=z)\cdot P(Z=z|X=x)$$ Similarly for the other abuses of notation in the question.

Comment: @Phise "The result should be $P(X)\cdot P(Y|X)$ to prove that Y is dependent on X when Z is not given" For your interest, the relation $$P(X,Y)=P(X)\cdot P(Y|X)$$ **always hold** hence it cannot help to prove any (in)dependence whatsoever. This is not the only mystery on this page, others being what you are really asking to show and how the accepted post is supposed to be an answer. Note that it may well happen that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, even with the dependence structure $$X\longrightarrow Z \longrightarrow Y$$ that you see to be interested in.

Comment: @Did Thank you for revealing and also comforting and reassuring comment.

Comment: @Did Very helpful feedback, thank you. I am trying to wrok on my terminology here, because this area is still very new to me. I made some changes to the question and hope things are more clearnow. Please tell me, if there is still something messed up.

Comment: Sorry but your question is still quite unclear: if $(X,Y,Z)$ are given fixed events, what do the sums over $Z$ in your question even mean?

Comment: "from P(X,Y)=P(X)⋅P(Y|X) we can deduce that Y is dependent on X" Again? Who says this? This is blatantly false.

Comment: @Did The sums over $Z$ in the equation was supposed to mean for all values $z$ that $Z$ can be. Now that I changed them to events I have to change that part. Anyway, that part is the probability that $X$ and $Y$ occur in case $Z$ occurs added with the case $Z$ does not occur.

I didn't say $P(X,Y)=P(X) \cdot P(Y|X)$ is correct. I was trying to explain, why I believed it was. Someone in the video said it and I wanted to figure out how to get to that equation, but now since it doesnt prove anything, I would like to know how to prove a dependency between $X$ and $Y$ when $Z$ doesnt occur.

Comment: The thing is that $P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y\mid X)$ is always true, by the definition of $P(Y\mid X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\Pr(Y|Z)=\Pr(Y|XZ)$. Consequently, $\Pr(Y|Z)\Pr(Z|X)=\Pr(Y|XZ)\Pr(Z|X)=\Pr(YZ|X)$

Comment: I can't quite follow. With that transformation I would get back to
$$P(X)* \sum_Z P(Y|Z)*P(Z|X) = P(X)* \sum_Z P(X,Y,Z)* \frac{1}{P(X)} = \sum_Z P(X,Y,Z)$$
But I would like to move forward to $P(X)*P(Y|X)$

Comment: $\sum_{Z} \Pr{(Y,Z|X)} = \Pr{(Y|X)}.$

Comment: Ah. I am sorry, the last part where you wrote $ ... P(YZ|X) = \frac{P(X,Y,Z)}{P(X)}$ confused me. 

I am still wondering why $\sum_Z P(Y,Z|X) = P(Y|X)$, could you explain that part ?

Comment: That's why I wrote $\Pr(YZ|X)=\frac{\Pr(XYZ)}{\Pr(X)}$. Since $\sum_{B}\Pr(A,B) = \Pr(A)$, $\sum_{Z} \Pr{(XYZ)}=\Pr(XY)$. Consequently, $\sum_{Z} \Pr{(YZ|X)}=\frac{1}{\Pr{(X)}} \sum_{Z} \Pr{(XYZ)}=\frac{\Pr(XY)}{\Pr(X)}=\Pr(Y|X)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your patience and your great answer! 
(Don't have enough rep though to rate your answer)